# Como paginar um retorno Json no PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Ola, então, tenho um request GET para uma API, que retorna um json, só que os registros são limitados a 100 por pagina, chegando em 100 ele retorna um parametro "next" com o link para proxima pagina... o problema é, como eu pegar todos os resultados e colocar numa array? eu fiz, porém não ta funcionando.... segue codigo... agradeço a ajuda...

[image]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Pode utlizar um slice no array:

```
 $array = array_slice($body2, 3);
```

E ir limitando ele conforme faz a paginação:

$array = array_slice($body2, -3, 3, true);

Comment: Mas como eu iria saber qual o proxima link da proxima pagina? cada pagina retorna um link diferente pra proxima pagina.

Comment: você usa um GET para isso.